# How do I set the accessibility name for a QPushButton that just has an icon?

Tags: windows, qt, accessibility

Qt version 4.8.1, building for Windows, I'm trying to get accessibility information to work  correctly for some buttons I have.

I have a QPushButton in my main window, which has an icon, thusly:

```
m_restartBtn = new QPushButton();
QPixmap rpm(":/images/Restart32x32.png");
QIcon ricn(rpm);
m_restartBtn->setIcon(ricn);
m_restartBtn->setIconSize(rpm.rect().size());
// put it in a box in the main layout
QHBoxLayout *buttonBox = new QHBoxLayout;
ui->mainLayout->addLayout(buttonBox);
buttonBox->addWidget(m_restartBtn);
```

Now that button shows up correctly, and if I hook up the signals it works fine. But when I  use the 'inspect.exe' (from the Win 7 SDK), I see that the button shows up, but has no name.

If I use `setText` instead of putting in an icon, the accessible name shows up correctly, but of course, I'm seeing text, not my icon. If I do both, then the accessible name works fine, but I get the text on screen, as one would expect.

I tried `setObjectName` and `setWindowTitle` just for laughs, and they of course didn't work.

Is there a proper way to set the accessible name for a QPushButton that only displays an icon?

My immediate goal is to remotely control the application for accessibility purposes. But I'd like the work to do double duty and get me full accessibility at the same time, so I don't have to do a separate effort later for accessibility.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You set the accessible name with [QWidget::setAccessibleName(const QString &name)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#accessibleName-prop), right?

Comment: @thuga, why not post it as an answer? I guess Michael didn't know the existence of this method, and then it is the exact answer he is looking for :-)

Comment: @Boris I actually did, but then I noticed he talks about setting the accessible name, so I thought maybe he did use that function and I decided to delete my answer. Anyway I undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [QWidget::setAccessibleName(const QString &name)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#accessibleName-prop).

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
button->setAccessibleName("name");
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I got so focused on QObject that I didn't examine QWidget closely enough. Thanks!